# Flutter svg animation and manipulation

Tags: flutter, dart, svg, frontend, svg-animate

I have an SVG asset of a map, in which I have to change the color of some cities depending on the results of a network call. On the web, one normally would add a `class` to each path, give it some CSS, and toggle that class using JavaScript.
How can I achieve the same effect in flutter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with the new version of `jovial_svg`.  It supports embedded stylesheets, so you can use CSS exactly as suggested.  Of course, you'd need to re-parse the SVG whenever there's a change, but that's not a big deal here.

Alternately, if it's just one set of cities, you could use SVG's currentColor, and set that value in the appropriate `ScalableImage` factory.  But for your use case, CSS seems like the better way to go.

NOTE:  At this exact moment, CSS support is in pre-release, but it should be formally released as 1.1.4 within a couple of days.  In the meantime, see https://pub.dev/packages/jovial_svg/versions/1.1.4-rc.3

Comment: Any code example of using embedded stylesheet ?

Comment: There are some SVG images that use it.  Grepping for '<style>' in the repo, I see there's https://github.com/zathras/jovial_svg/blob/main/demo/assets/svg/stylesheet.svg , and over in https://github.com/zathras/jovial_svg/tree/main/test/more_test_images there's:

cdata.svg:  <style>
coverage3.svg:    <style>
coverage4.svg:<style>
opacity_in_style.svg:    <style>
opacity_in_style_2.svg:    <style>
opacity_in_style_3.svg:    <style>
rgba.svg:  <style>
style.svg:  <style>
style.svg:  <style>
style_text.svg:<style>